# NullPointerException on views outside of OnActivityCreated/OnCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

When any sort of view is called outside of the `OnCreateView` method (or `OnActivtivityCreated` method for that matter, I have tried both), I get a `NullPointerException`. To communicate between fragments, I used the interface method which, through my research, seems to be the best way to do it. Unfortunately, I suspect that my error comes from the way that the `MainActivity` finds the Fragments.

To try to debug what I have so far, I used `System.out.println()` on the object in `OnCreateView()/OnActivityCreated()` and there is a memory address meaning it exists and is NOT null, yet when I call it outside of the function from `MainActivity`, it becomes null...?

Can someone shed some light into my situation? Thanks! (BTW, I have taken some useless parts of the code out)

Tab2Home.java

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    spinner = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tipSpinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.tipArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    serviceRate=(RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.serviceBar);

    //THE OBJECT BELOW IS WHERE THE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION IS COMING FROM
    billAmount = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
    System.out.println(billAmount); //Surprisingly, this is not null IN the method.

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

}

public void transferInfo(){
    double bill;
    if (String.valueOf(billAmount.getText()).isEmpty()) //billAmount is null OUTSIDE of the method.
        bill = 0.00;
    else
        bill = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(billAmount.getText()));
    odsl.setData(       //odsl is the OnDataSetListener object.
            bill,
            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner.getItemAtPosition(3))),
            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numPeopleEdit.getText()))
            );
}

public interface OnDataSetListener {
    public void setData(double bill, int tip, int ppl);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        odsl = (OnDataSetListener) context;
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

And the MainActivity.java

```
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 2){
                Tab2Home homefrag = (Tab2Home) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
                homefrag.transferInfo();
                System.out.println(".transferInfo() has been called");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 3){
                Tab2Home homefrag = (Tab2Home) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
                homefrag.transferInfo();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void setData(double bill, int tip, int ppl) {
    Tab3Summary summaryfrag = (Tab3Summary) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
    summaryfrag.updateInfo(bill, tip, ppl);

}
```

EDIT:

Here is the error message:

```
05-23 02:28:00.352 31339-31339/com.uottawa.bond.simpletip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.uottawa.bond.simpletip, PID: 31339
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.uottawa.bond.simpletip.Tab2Home.transferInfo(Tab2Home.java:97)
                                                                            at com.uottawa.bond.simpletip.MainActivity$1.onPageScrolled(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1954)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1928)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.pageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1866)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1826)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16037)
                                                                            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16834)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1195)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16050)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16013)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16013)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16013)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16013)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16013)
                                                                            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
                                                                            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
                                                                            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: where you are getting null ? put your stacktrace and your layout file

Comment: You can move code from onActivityCreated to onViewCreated and change getActivity().findVi... to view.findView....

Comment: If your `spinner` and other widget do belongs to your `fragment` layout, `getActivity().findViewById()` will return `null`. Instead use reference them into `onViewCreated()` without using `getActivity()`.

Comment: I have already tried referencing them in onViewCreated() already.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

1.override the below method

2.Instead of getActivity().findviewbYId use **rootView**

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tipSpinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.tipArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    serviceRate=(RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.serviceBar);
    billAmount = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
    System.out.println(billAmount); 
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that as a solution but it does not work. I tried putting it into onViewCreated(), onCreateView(), and onActivityCreated() but it still does not work.